Hiding a parent div based on all child inputs being disabled
I am trying to {display:none} on class="filter-form__group" only if ALL child Input's are 'disabled'.
<div class="filter-form__group">
  <div class="filter-form__group-filter-wrapper" data-filter-type="list">
    <div class="filter-form__list-wrapper">
      <ul class="filter-form__list">
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Luggage" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Motorcycle" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Thanks!
I tried some CSS but they do not seem to work and I believe this may have to be done in JS.

CSS-only solution:

Hide by default the groups
Unhide the groups that have at least one input not disabled



.filter-form__group {
  display: none;
  
  &:has(input:not(:disabled)) {
    display: initial;
  }
}
<div class="filter-form__group">
  <p>GROUP: all disabled</p>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Luggage" disabled>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Motorcycle" disabled>
</div>
<div class="filter-form__group">
  <p>GROUP one is not disabled</p>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Luggage" disabled>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Motorcycle">
</div>




Iterate over the potentially disabled elements and push truthy comparisons into an empty array. Then compare the length of the array and input elements nodeList length and add/remove a helper class to the target element accordingly.


function disableGroup(el) {
  const group = document.querySelector(el); // get the group parent element
  const inputs = group.querySelectorAll('input'); // get inputs
  const result = []; // empty array 
  inputs.forEach(input => { // loop over the inputs
    input.disabled ? result.push(true) : null; // if input.disabled push true into array   
  });   
  result.length === inputs.length ? // compare the two lengths
    group.classList.add('none') : // if they are equal add helper class
    group.classList.remove('none') // if not remove helper class
}

disableGroup('.filter-form__group');

disableGroup('.filter-form__group2');
.none {
  display: none;
}
Do not display filter-form__group if all input childNodes are disabled

<div class="filter-form__group">
  <div class="filter-form__group-filter-wrapper" data-filter-type="list">
    <div class="filter-form__list-wrapper">
      <ul class="filter-form__list">
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            Form group 1:<input type="checkbox" value="Luggage" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            Form group 1:<input type="checkbox" value="Motorcycle" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filter-form__group2">
  <div class="filter-form__group-filter-wrapper" data-filter-type="list">
    <div class="filter-form__list-wrapper">
      <ul class="filter-form__list">
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            Form group 2:<input type="checkbox" value="Luggage" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            Form group 2:<input type="checkbox" value="Motorcycle">
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




It would've been nice if you provided an example of what you tried yourself.
Anyway, here's an (js) idea:


console.log(`wait a sec...`);

setTimeout(disableAllAndMonitor, 2000);

// use a monitoring function to periodically
// check the 'disabled' state of the checkboxes
function monitorDisabledCBs() {
  const disabledCheckboxes = document
    .querySelectorAll(`.filter-form__group input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)`);

  if (disabledCheckboxes.length < 1) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`There you have it, div.filter-form__group is hidden`);
    return document.querySelector(`.filter-form__group`).style.display = `none`;
  }
  
  return setTimeout(monitorDisabledCBs, 500);
}


function disableAllAndMonitor() {
  document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="checkbox"]`)
    .forEach(cb => cb.disabled = `disabled`);
  monitorDisabledCBs();  
}
<div class="filter-form__group">
  <div class="filter-form__group-filter-wrapper" data-filter-type="list">
    <div class="filter-form__list-wrapper">
      <ul class="filter-form__list">
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Luggage" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Motorcycle" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



But I think you'd better use Roko C. Buljan's answer

Try this, mostly will work
JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2e34tzjq/
const filterFormGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-form__group');
filterFormGroups.forEach(group => {
  const inputs = group.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const allDisabled = Array.from(inputs).every(input => input.disabled);
  if (allDisabled) {
    group.style.display = 'none';
  }
});


Some cleaner javascript code if you still want to use it over CSS.


function toggleParentHiddenAttribute(parentClass) {
  const parentEl = document.querySelector(`.${parentClass}`);
  const numberOfInputs = parentEl.querySelectorAll('input').length;
  const numberOfHiddenInputs = parentEl.querySelectorAll('input[disabled]').length;
  
  parentEl.hidden = numberOfInputs == numberOfHiddenInputs;
  
  // returning for the console.log
  return numberOfInputs == numberOfHiddenInputs
}

let parentClass = 'filter-form__group1';

console.log(parentClass, toggleParentHiddenAttribute(parentClass));

parentClass = 'filter-form__group2';

console.log(parentClass, toggleParentHiddenAttribute(parentClass));
<div class="filter-form__group1">
  <div class="filter-form__group-filter-wrapper" data-filter-type="list">
    <div class="filter-form__list-wrapper">
      <ul class="filter-form__list">
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Luggage" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Motorcycle" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="filter-form__group2">
  <div class="filter-form__group-filter-wrapper" data-filter-type="list">
    <div class="filter-form__list-wrapper">
      <ul class="filter-form__list">
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Luggage">
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-item">
          <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Motorcycle" disabled>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Yep, you’re right—this is something that CSS can't do. Since you need to check if all the input elements inside a specific group are disabled, JavaScript will work.
Here’s how I would do it:
document.querySelectorAll('.filter-form__group').forEach(function(group) {
    const inputItems = group.querySelectorAll('input');
    const allDisabled = Array.from(inputItems).every(input => input.disabled);

    if (allDisabled) {
        group.style.display = 'none';
    }
});


Thanks for the prompt reply ebilly, unfortunately it still isn't working with the above JS.

here is a URL where you can see what I am trying to accomplish. Basically I want to remove the entire category if all inputs are disabled.
https://motoheaven.com.au/collections/2022-yamaha-yzf-r1?sort_by=manual&filter.p.m.my_fields.sub_category=Battery&filter.v.price.gte=&filter.v.price.lte=

CSS can accomplish this. Use :has and :not
